# sorting a mmaped file with random integers in C

Tags: c, mmap, qsort

I'm trying to create a C program that creates a txt file with random integers, and then `mmap` the said file and `qsort` it. Creating the txt and mapping goes smoothly, but I can't figure out why `qsort` just destroys it. My guess, it's something to do with data types, but even after playing around with them, I get more or less the same result.

compar:

```
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return (*(const int *)p1 - *(const int *)p2);
}
```

mmap and qsort:

```
    char *addr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myFile, 0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         printf("%c", addr[i]);
    qsort(addr, 20, sizeof(char), cmp);
    printf("\n-------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         printf("%c", addr[i]);
```

output example:

```
10
19
9
8
18
2
9
6
3
7
15
12
12
14
6
2
4
3
15
13

-------------

296

1
9
93818
1
0

7
15
12
12
14
6
2
4
3
15
13
```

So 20 random integers are created in txt and mapped with no problems. But I guess `qsort` doesn't like what's given to it.
I tried having `mmap` as `int`, but that created other problems like incorrect numbers in the array and incorrect amount of numbers and some 0s (perhaps I handled the output incorrectly). I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. here is the full code in case if it's needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
void rand_txt(int size);

int main() {

    rand_txt(20);

    int myFile = open("rand.txt", O_RDWR);
    struct stat myStat = {};
    fstat(myFile, &myStat);
    off_t size = myStat.st_size;

    char *addr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myFile, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", addr[i]);

    qsort(addr, 20, sizeof(char), cmp);
    printf("\n-------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", addr[i]);

    return 0;
}

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return (*(const int*)p1 - *(const int*)p2);
}

//Function to create a txt with random integers in given size
void rand_txt(int size) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("rand.txt", "w");
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", (rand() % size) + 1);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Also a quickie:
Do the arrays and pointers behave in the same way in practice(like strings)? say we declare:
`int *x = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };`
can we just `fprint("%d\t", x[i]);`
or such type of arrays must be declared as `int[] = { 10, 20... };` and not with pointers?
(I can and will test it myself and edit the "quickie" out if there is no answer until after I am able to test and study it)

Comment: You need to have fixed size elements for qsort to work. You could for example allow for 8 characters for the numbers + nl and cr characters.

Comment: `qsort(addr, 20, sizeof(char), cmp);`, that `sizeof(char)` is *not* the size of each "item" in your sequence. An, in fact, if your sequence is actually *text*, where each item is of disparate length (maybe 1, 2, 3, etc. digits), `qsort` won't work *at all* (at least directly).  The `qsort` function is all about sorting a fixed-length sequence of items of consistent size *each*.

Comment: @WhozCraig What if the textual representation of the numbers has a fixed size?

Comment: @Tarik which it (a) doesn't in the OPs case, and (b) would no longer mate with the disqualifying "where each item is of disparate length" condition mentioned in my comment. Even if the textual rep was consistent, the cast to `const int*` is not going to do what the OP assumes.

Comment: @WhozCraig Fair enough, I failed to read you through.

Comment: If the numbers have a fixed-length text representation, then you need to compare them as fixed-length byte arrays and not as integers.  Your comparison function is all wrong — it is trying to compare the wrong types.  There's a fair chance that, on some systems, you'd be crashing with SIGBUS errors, though it depends on how big your fixed-size integer records are.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well there are two options: either have the numbers fixed length and right justified and compare the strings or have the numbers fixed length and have the compare function convert each string to an int and compare the integers. I agree strcmp would not work since the strings are not null terminated. strncmp could be used instead.

Comment: You should have tried this on a regular array

Comment: "the cast to const int* is not going to do what the OP assumes" it might, UB of course but surprisingly 70% of the time it works all the time ;)

Comment: Using `int *x = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };` won't work.  Assuming you have C99 or later, you could use `int *x = (int[]){ 10, 20, 30, 40 };`, which is compound literal array and the pointer to the first element (10) is assigned to `x`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. LOLz. I've always been a bit of a hard luck case; for me it rarely exceeds 58% of the time working all the time. Some people just somehow manage to walk between the raindrops.

Comment: Just as an aside, the easiest solution here is to stop formatting the integers as text in the first place. You can write a binary file full of native `int`s, mmap and qsort that file, and do human-readable formatting later (even just with `od -t d4 -w4 -A none` or something)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see, for some reason I thought it would work like char pointer as in `char *pr = "blah";` because of that I had the idea that pointers behave in the same way as arrays and thus this would work, but yeah it doesn't and is pretty wrong

Comment: @Useless at some point I'll have mixed chars and integers in the txt file and I'll have to sort them, I'm trying to understand how qsort and mmap work, and how they can work together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot sort a text file with numbers of different sizes by mapping the file in memory and calling `qsort()` with the comparison function for multiple reasons:

- `qsort` needs an array where all entries have the same size, which is not the case of textual representations.
- the comparison function assumes an array of `int`, not an array of textual representations
- even for an array of `int`, the comparison function would be inappropriate for large absolute values as the subtraction might overflow.

To sort the text file, the classic approach is to allocate an array of `int` and load the values from the file, converting from text representation to `int` values, sort the array with `qsort` with an appropriate comparison function, and write the sorted array converting back to string representations.

Here is a comparison function you can use:

```
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const int *i1 = p1;
    const int *i2 = p2;
    return (*i1 > *i2) - (*i1 < *i2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code does is what you wrote. There is no `qsort` "likes", or function "thinks".

You write text line by line, like below. Do notice the end of line characters:

> ```
> 10\n
> 19\n
> 9\n
> ```

The below function

```
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return (*(const int*)p1 - *(const int*)p2);
}
```

Takes two pointers, interprets them as `int*` and compares two `int`s being pointed to. Type `int` has typically 32-bit length.
I will write your text in one line and see what will `cmp` function do.

```
  p1        p2
  |         |
  v         v
 10\n1   9\n9\n
```

The comparator will get bytes `10\n1`, interpret them as an `int`.
Then it will get bytes `9\n9\n`, interpret them as an `int`. And compare those `int`s.

As others have pointed out in comments section, `qsort` may access past the data that you wrote to the file. That case, comparator will compare bytes values, that it finds in a `mmap`ed memory.

**int *x = {10, 20, 30, 40};**

Turn on compiler warnings and see what will it tell you. Maybe try to print `x[0], x[1]`. Why are you asking that **quickey**? Do you trip into imaginary `C` language?

Answer (score 0):

You should set format for your strings(with constant length and zero left padding):

```c
fprintf(fp, "%015d\n", (rand() % size*5) + 1)
```

and then use same length+1 at size argument in `qsort` function.

You should also change the ‍‍`cmp` function as follows so that it converts the string into a number by `atoi`:

```c
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const int i1 = atoi((char*)p1);
    const int i2 = atoi((char*)p2);
    return (i1 - i2);
}
```

My suggested code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const int i1 = atoi((char*)p1);
    const int i2 = atoi((char*)p2);
    return (i1 - i2);
}
//Function to create a txt with random integers in given size
void rand_txt(int size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    FILE *fp = fopen("rand.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "%015d\n", (rand() % size*5) + 1);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    int COUNT=20;
    rand_txt(COUNT);
    int myFile = open("rand.txt", O_RDWR);
    struct stat myStat = {};
    fstat(myFile, &myStat);
    off_t size = myStat.st_size;

    char *addr =(char*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myFile, 0);
    close(myFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", addr[i]);

    qsort(addr, COUNT, 16, cmp);
    printf("\n-------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", addr[i]);
    munmap(NULL, size);
    return 0;
}
```